# Force macro expansion

Tags: macros, expansion

I am writing a macro that will read a system of linear equations in a custom format and call `\begin{array}` with the appropriate format. For that I need to loop through each row and compute what is going to be displayed.

This is what I have so far.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\lineareqsys}[3]{
\noexpandarg
\StrCount{#3}{\\}[\rows] %check \rows = arg > 0
\newcounter{i} \setcounter{i}{0}
\def\str{#3}
\def\strout{}
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\str}{+}{+&}[\str]
\expandafter\StrSubstitute\expandafter{\str}{-}{-&}[\str]
\loop
\stepcounter{i}
\expandafter\def\csname strout\roman{i}\endcsname{}
\expandafter\StrCut\expandafter{\str}{\\}{\str}{\rest}
\expandafter\StrPosition\expandafter{\str}{x}[\xpos]
\expandafter\StrLeft\expandafter{\str}{\xpos}[\strappx]
\expandafter\def\expandafter\strout\expandafter{\strout \strappx &}
\expandafter\StrGobbleLeft\expandafter{\str}{\xpos}[\str]
\expandafter\StrPosition\expandafter{\str}{y}[\ypos]
\expandafter\StrLeft\expandafter{\str}{\ypos}[\strappy]
\expandafter\def\expandafter\strout\expandafter{\strout \strappy &}
\expandafter\StrGobbleLeft\expandafter{\str}{\ypos}[\str]
\expandafter\StrPosition\expandafter{\str}{=}[\eqpos]
\expandafter\StrLeft\expandafter{\str}{\eqpos}[\strappeq]
\expandafter\def\expandafter\strout\expandafter{\strout \strappeq &}
\expandafter\StrGobbleLeft\expandafter{\str}{\eqpos}[\str]
\expandafter\StrRight\expandafter{\str}{\eqpos}[\strapplb]
\expandafter\def\expandafter\strout\expandafter{\strout \strapplb \\}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\str\expandafter{\rest}
\expandafter\def\csname strout\roman{i}\endcsname{\strout}
\ifnum \thei < #1 \relax
\repeat
\newcounter{j} \setcounter{j}{0}
\def\alig{r}
\loop
\stepcounter{j}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\alig\expandafter{\alig cr}
\ifnum \thej < #2 \relax
\repeat
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{\alig}
\strout
\end{array}
\right.
}


\begin{document}
$\lineareqsys{2}{2}{
x + y = 5 \\
x - y = 3 \\
}$
\end{document}
```

There is a problem with line

```
\expandafter\def\csname strout\roman{i}\endcsname{\strout}
```

because `\strout` is not fully expanded, so after the second time of the loop data is replaced and I get the last row repeated twice.

I've been checking other threads but I haven't managed to get it right. How can I solve this problem?

Note1: The code isn't finished so it doesn't handle the cases where there is no `x` or `y` or a line starts with a `-` sign.

Note2: The format I was referring to is straightforward.

```
ax + by + cz = d \\
```

for as many rows as necessary.

Edit: Simpler version of previous code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\lineareqsys}{
\newcounter{i} \setcounter{i}{0}
\def\strout{}
\loop
\stepcounter{i}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\strout\expandafter{\strout \arabic{i} row \\}
\ifnum \thei < 2 \relax
\repeat
\begin{array}{l}
\strout
\end{array}
}
\begin{document}
$\lineareqsys$
\end{document}
```

This ilustrates the same problem. `\arabic{i}` is expanded at the end when it's value is 2. Not dinamic.

Comment: if you know that `\strout` is safe for expansion then just replace `\def` by `\edef` or if you just want to expand it once then `expandafter\def\csname strout\roman{i}\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\strout}` but the code seems massively over complicated, can you give a small text description of the intended effect?

Comment: ``\edef`` gives a compile time error. I think because it relays on ``#3`` but I'm not sure if this is the reason.

Comment: Do you know about the `systeme` package?

Comment: don't do `\newcounter` inside a command! (you do it twice)

Comment: @egreg Yes, I had found it previously. I wanted to write my own functions though, so I can add things as I see fit.

Comment: Your edit only illustrates _another_ problem. In you original code, the `\csname strout\roman{i}\endcsname` serve to nothing at all. They are defined (wrongly) but not used (at all).

Comment: @jfbu I created it while trying to solve the problem. It is true it is not used in that piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core problem is that you are not expanding things. As you can see, here is meaning of `\strout` after a while

```
> \strout=macro:
->\strappx &\strappy &\strappeq &\strapplb \\\strappx &\strappy &\strappeq &\st
rapplb \\.
\iterate ... {\strout \strapplb \\} \show \strout 
                                                  \expandafter \def \expanda...
l.57 }
      $
```

You have to find a way to add to `\strout` the *expanded contents* of the `\strappx`, `\strappy` etc... whatever they are.

Besides, you do `\newcounter` inside your command call, which is very wrong. But this is other issue.

To debug, I added `\show\strout` at various places of your command.

Also you are lucky to call this macro only in math mode because you have tons of space tokens in it.

---

For example, this can give an idea of what needs to be done:

```
%\expandafter\def\expandafter\strout\expandafter{\strout \strapplb \\}
\expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\strout\expandafter{\strapplb\\}
```

[image]

The RHS of first equation is fixed.

Comment: This works. Any alternative to ``\g@addto@macro`` by any chance?

Comment: well, `\edef\strout{\unexpanded\expandafter{\strout}\unexpanded\expandafter{\strapplb\\}}` should work (pay attention that copying pasting from this comment might introduce some invisible Unicode, due to the site interfering; better copy by hand). Beware that `\g@addto@macro` is global, so if you use it make global all other manipulations of `\strout` to follow good practices.

Comment: this being said, it would not be too complicated to replace by delimited macros all your invocations of `xstring` ... and the various pieces would then be available "raw" not incorporated in a macro.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with the last comment. How do I search for x, y and z and how do I cut the users input into two pieces without a string package?
Can you refer me to some documentation? I'm pretty new to TeX, previously I've only used high level LaTeX commands.

Comment: maybe my comment was a bit rushed. TeX has a a powerful concept of delimited macros, on which evidently packages such as `xstring` build up, or `xparse`. If you happen to know about TeX, it is natural to feel you don't really need `xstring`, but it also means you have your own coding habits and possibly you re-invent the wheel each time. If x, y, z are always in that order, delimited macros will solve easily problem. If the order maybe z, y, x, then they will too (only available tool after all) but require more expertise. TeX by Topic (`texdoc topic`)  is recommended.

Answer (score 2):

There are big expansion problems, as you saw.

Here's a completely different solution, which uses `expl3`, but has, like yours, the defect that missing unknowns spoil the result.

I also offer a comparison with `systeme`, that doesn't suffer from the defect.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
%\usepackage{array} % also works with this uncommented
\usepackage{systeme} % for comparison

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\lineareqsys}{mm}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__mendus_system_in_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  \seq_clear:N \l__mendus_system_out_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__mendus_system_in_seq
   {
    \__mendus_system_make_row:nn { #1 } { ##1 }
   }
  \left\lbrace
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \exp_args:Nnx \begin{array}{r \prg_replicate:nn { \clist_count:n { #1 } } { c r } }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__mendus_system_out_seq { \\ }
  \end{array}
  \right.
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__mendus_system_make_row:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__mendus_system_row_tl { #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (.+?)(\+|\-|\=) } { \1\cB\{\cE\}\2\cB\{\cE\}\cT& } \l__mendus_system_row_tl
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { ##1 } { \cL##1 \cT& } \l__mendus_system_row_tl
   }
  \seq_put_right:NV \l__mendus_system_out_seq \l__mendus_system_row_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_count:nnN { nV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\lineareqsys{x,y}{
x + y = 5 \\
x - y = 3 \\
}
\qquad
\lineareqsys{x,y,z}{
  2x-3y+4z=0 \\
  x+12y-z=0 \\
  -x+8y+z=3
}
\]

\[
\systeme{
  x + y = 5,
  x - y = 3
}
\qquad
\systeme{
  2x-3y+4z=0,
  x+12y-z=0,
  -x+8y+z=3
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]